# find and modify date patterns succeeding a pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string with some dates succeeded by a pattern FXTKLN.

JHSHSS20NOV2012 GHHSEE23FEB2011 FXTKLN

My requirement is to find the dates 20NOV2012, 23FEB2012 succeeded by the pattern FXTKLN and replace those dates with DATE20NOV2012DATE, DATE23FEB2012DATE and so on. There can be many dates - not just two.

Cheers,
Pearl

Comment: **rolling the dates forward** can u elaborate more on this..Also which language r u using!

Comment: `20NOV2012` in your example is not directly succeeded by `FXTKLN` - should it be replaced with `DATE...DATE` or not? and why?

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It Sorry for the late reply. I am using python. The requirement is to pad all the dates appearing before FXTKLN with DATE as an identifier. It need not be directly succeeded by FXTKLN.

Answer (score 1):

> find the dates 20NOV2012, 23FEB2012 succeeded by the pattern FXTKLN

Use this regex

```
\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}(?=.*?FXTKLN)
```

The above `regex` contains

```
\d{1,2}// matches 1 to 2 digits
[a-zA-Z]{3} //matches 3 characters 
\d{4} //matches 4 digits
(?=.*?FXTKN) //checks if the date is followed by FXTKN considering multile dates before it!
```

> I got to replace those dates with DATE20NOV2012DATE

Use this regex which now uses groups

`(\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4})(?=.*?FXTKLN)`

and then replace it with

`DATE$1DATE`

Comment: Thanks. I got to replace those dates with DATE20NOV2012DATE, DATE23FEB2012DATE and so on too.

Comment: @user1785842 if the answer has helped u ,u can accept the answer